# SocketTimeoutException when trying to run DataFlow job locally with PubSub input source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to test my DataFlow job locally, but keep getting timeout errors on reading from PubSub topic.

```
PCollection<KV<Integer, Tick>> input = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic(options.getPubSubTopic()).maxNumRecords(10))
```

I'm sure that topic name is correct since the DataFlow is correctly creating subscription under desired topic each time I run the job and I can see it in the browser.

Any hints what might be the issue here?

Comment: Could you post more details about the exception you're getting?

Comment: @BenChambers it turns out that it was bc. topic was empty - I was sure that's not the case since I was checking API Manager and I could see call count for Pub/Sub increasing with Error 0% and in fact I was getting http code 400 when publishing a message :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the topic was empty.  Even though there were attempted publish calls to the topic, they were failing with 400s, so nothing made it to the pipeline's subscription.